# How to align button in top right corner inside Dialog angular material?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I want to align button in top right corner inside dialog angular material. The problem is that I have some space between button and corner of dialog, and I don't want it. [image]

This is my html code:

```html
<button #btnClose mat-button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

and this is my css code:

```css
.close {
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 2vw !important;
  min-width: 2vw !important;
}
```

I can do some "trick" in css with margin, but I think that is bad idea:

```css
.close {
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 2vw !important;
  min-width: 2vw !important;
  margin: -1.2vw -1.2vw;
}
```

and than I get what I want:

[image]

Any better solution?
P.S: It has to be responsive.

Comment: if you want it there ( without looking at any other CSS code ), you could just do position: absolute; right: 0px; ( with the parent container containing a position:relative )

Comment: The parent container likely has some padding around it. Either go with what @Keith has suggested or remove the padding from the parent container.

Comment: Around button and title is this code: <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"> </form>, and this is angular material popup... Maybe there is some default padding here?

Comment: The same solution suggested by Keith, I will do position:absolute and make sure the parent container is in position:relative so that the close button will not place outside the modal, Simplest way I guess.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to align something in the top right, you can use:

```css
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: This code puts the button at the top right of the screen, not modal.

Comment: The element around the ".close" element has to be "position: relative". An absolute element always aligns to the next relative element it can find.